# django-registration auto create UserProfile

Tags: django, profile, django-registration

I'm using django-registration and I'm trying to connect to its signals to automatically create a UserProfile.

Signal definition:

```
from django.dispatch import Signal

# A new user has registered.
user_registered = Signal(providing_args=["user", "request"])
```

Signal send by django-registration:

```
    def register(self, request, **kwargs):
    """
    Create and immediately log in a new user.

    """
    username, email, password = kwargs['username'], kwargs['email'], kwargs['password1']
    User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)

    # authenticate() always has to be called before login(), and
    # will return the user we just created.
    new_user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    login(request, new_user)
    signals.user_registered.send(sender=self.__class__,
                                 user=new_user,
                                 request=request)
    return new_user
```

My signal connect:

```
from registration.signals import *
from core.models import UserProfile
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def createUserProfile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)

user_registered.connect(createUserProfile, sender=User)
```

Needless to say no UserProfile is being created. What am I missing here?

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT:** I moved my connect() and its corresponding method to a model.py and still no luck.

New code:

```
from django.db import models

from django.contrib import auth
from django.contrib.auth import login
from core.forms import AuthForm
from registration.signals import *
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# Create your models here.

class UserProfile(models.Model) :
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.user.username


def createUserProfile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    print "creating profile"
    UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance)

user_registered.connect(createUserProfile, sender=User)
```

I'm using Pycharm to debug, and in the very beginning my breakpoint on user_registered.connect() is hit. So I assume that connect() is being registered correctly. However, I still don't see createUserProfile being run. Anything else I'm missing?

Thanks!

**ANSWER:** Doh. My connect and receiver code was wrong. Correct code:

```
def createUserProfile(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)

user_registered.connect(createUserProfile)
```

Realized it after I read signals.py in django-registration

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to register (connect) your signal in a module which is imported on server startup. Your file where `user_registered.connect(createUserProfile, sender=User)`lives is mot likely not imported on startup. From the django docs:

> You can put signal handling and
>   registration code anywhere you like.
>   However, you'll need to make sure that
>   the module it's in gets imported early
>   on so that the signal handling gets
>   registered before any signals need to
>   be sent. This makes your app's
>   models.py a good place to put
>   registration of signal handlers.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions

So models.py of your custom app would be a good place (or any other module which is definitely imported on server startup).

Comment: I changed my code according to your answer, but still no luck. Please check my edits. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Torsten is right: the alternative way is to use [decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/a/739665/892951) as stated in [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions):

```
    from registration.signals import user_registered
    # ...
    @receiver(user_registered)
    def your_function_name_here(sender, user, request, **kwargs):
            # your code here
            pass
```

I like this way because it's compact and readable.