# RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no userprofile

Tags: python, django, django-authentication

So I've extended my user with the field `score` like this:

models.py:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0);
```

which seemed to be along the lines of the [recommended way](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model).

Then I tried to access the user's `userprofile` in my views:

**views.py:**

```
player = request.user.userprofile
```

which seemed to align with the recommended way as well, but that is where I get my error:

```
RelatedObjectDoesNotExist
User has no userprofile.
```

If I change `userprofile` to something else I get another error:

```
AttributeError
'User' object has no attribute 'flowerpot'
```

When I try the following code:

```
print request.user
print UserProfile.objects.all()
```

I get the console output:

```
post_test1
[]
```

**EDIT**
I have two superusers, seven users I created before extending the user, and one user (post_test1) that I created after extending the user.

---

**EDIT 2**

It seams clear that what I need is to create a `post_save` handler that creates a new profile whenever the User object is created.

This seemed simple enough when I read it, went to the [page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/) that was linked to, which was a list of all the signals Django sends. I looked up `post_save` and it said:

> Like pre_save, but sent at the end of the save() method.

Alright, so I look up `pre_save` and it says:

> This is sent at the beginning of a model’s save() method.

I've interpreted it like this: When I create my user (in my `views.py`) the `save()` method should be called, which hasn't been the case up until now, and after that a `post_save` should be sent(?), which will create a new profile whenever the User object is created!

So now I'm ready to start looking at examples, so I google:

`django post save example`
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13016982/4136445) it looks like I'm supposed to add something that looks like a decorator `@receiver(post_save, ...`
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5658745/django-registration-auto-create-userprofile) it looks like I'm supposed to alter multiple files and write a signal definition?
[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910359/creating-a-extended-user-profile) also seems to imply multiple files (including a `signals.py`)

It looks like there's a lot more to it than I first thought. Could anyone here either explain how I'm to do this or show me to some good resources on how signals work?

Right now my `create_user` view look like this:

```py
def create_user(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UserCreationForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data["username"]
            password = form.cleaned_data["password1"]
            new_user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, password=password)
            return redirect('play')
    else:
        form = UserCreationForm()

    return render(request, 'antonymapp/create_user.html', {'form': form})
```

Should I call `new_user.save()` before returning? If yes, why has it worked up until now? I have a bunch of users that I've created while testing this view. It also looks like somewhere around here `post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)` should be added?

Comment: `RelatedObjectDoesNotExist` means there's no `userprofile` related to `request.user`, it's kind of obvious, isn't it?

Comment: I extended user with userprofile and still there's no userprofile related to request user. So yeah, you're right. That's obviously the problem I'm asking about here.

Comment: did you setup the userprofile in settings file? for example if your app name is base then you need to add this in your settings file.
`AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'base.UserProfile'`

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You have to create a `userprofile` for the user first:

```
profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=request.user)
```

In your `views.py` you can use `get_or_create` so that a `userprofile` is created for a user if the user doesn't have one.

```
player, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
```

**UPDATE**: For automatically creating user profiles every time a new user is made, use signals.

In `myapp/signals.py` do something like this:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User, dispatch_uid='save_new_user_profile')
def save_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    user = instance
    if created:
        profile = UserProfile(user=user)
        profile.save()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  
What's the recommended way of doing this? Should I do this in the create_user view? 

Where could I read up on this (wondering for example of how I'd go about creating userprofiles for admin and previously created users but don't want to waste your time with a bunch of follow up questions =)

Comment: You can either use `get_or_create` to ensure user has profile when he/she visits the page Or you can create a `post_save` signal to create profile every time a new user is created.

Comment: Thanks! So I don't have to do anything in my views.py-file? It feels like I've just created a function (save_profile) that I should call somewhere?

Comment: Nope, you are not required to call it anywhere. It gets executed on its own every time a user is created/updated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107786/discussion-between-mrjalapeno-and-v1k45).

Answer (score 6):

If you are getting this error even if you've tried the suggestions above, it may caused by the fact that the first user you had created (with createsuperuser command) does not have a profile.

I was getting this error when I tried to login with that user. I solved it this way:

-Create a new user.

-Undo the changes. (Erase the code you've written for Profile or make them comment lines)

-Log in to your superuser.

-Give admin authorization to newly created user.

Now you can delete the first user. (The user with no profile)

Answer (score 3):

Nothing in what you've done forces the creation of a `UserProfile` object when a `User` is created. There are two basic ways of handling this:

1. If you always want a `UserProfile` to exist (which seems like the case as you give a `default` value to `score`, create a [`post_save`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/signals/#post-save) handler that creates a new profile when ever the `User` object is created (but not every time it's saved, so make sure to check the `created` argument in the handler).
2. If it's expected a user may not have a profile, you need to catch the `UserProfile.DoesNotExist` exception when trying to access it. If you do this frequently, make some kind of helper function.

UPDATED TO ANSWER SIGNAL QUESTION

> It also looks like somewhere around here `post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)` should be added?

You would need to define a function called `create_profile` and then wire it up as you have shown. I typically do this right in the `models.py` file that includes the `sender` but in this case where the sender is a built-in Django model and you're already importing that model into the file where you define your `UserProfile` that's the place to do it. It would look something like:

```
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    # ignore if this is an existing User
    if not created:
        return
    UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem (= User exists, Profile does not but there is OneToOne relation introduced from Profile side) so I could not log in to Admin site. The app was already in production, and I could not trash the database.

The solution was to create a temporary view function `fixme` with no login requirements (but a hard-to-guess URL) and visit it once. The view queried for all User objects, and then reverse-queried for the Profile of each User with `get_or_create()`. If Profile was not there, it was created.

Print was for monitoring success through logs. Finally removed the view and URL from the production app.

```
def fixme(request):
    users = User.objects.all()
    for user in users:
        obj, created = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
        print(user.username,' : ',created)
    print("all done")
    return HttpResponse("It's done.")
```

Answer (score 1):

First Register profile model in admin.py if not already done.

Create new superuser using ./manage.py createsuperuser.

Log in with new superuser.

From Admin panel click Profile and add new entry and selct user from user dropdown and save.

Comment: Problem, I cannot login with the superuser, because the profile is not there.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this problem (Django 3.8.3-Mongodb). Firstly, I created signals.py, then I added apps.py in project.

**signals.py**

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import Profile

@receiver(post_save,sender=User)
def update_user_profile(sender,instance,created,**kwargs):
    if created:
        profile = Profile.objects.create(user =instance)
```

**apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class ProfileConfig(AppConfig):
    default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
    name = 'Profile'

    def ready(self):
        import Profile.signals
```

**views.py**

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls.base import reverse
from .forms import ProfileForm
from .models import Profile
from django.shortcuts import redirect, render,get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash
from django.contrib.auth.forms import PasswordChangeForm

login_required(login_url="user:login")
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request,"dashboard.html")


@login_required(login_url="user:login")
def get_profile(request):    
    
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile,user=request.user)
    
    return render(request,"profile.html",{"profile":profile})

@login_required(login_url="user:login")
def update_profile(request):       
    profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=request.user)
    form = ProfileForm(instance=profile)
    if request.method=="POST":
        form = ProfileForm(request.POST,request.FILES,instance=request.user.user_profile)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            messages.success(request,"Profile is updated successfully")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("profile:profile"))   
        else:
            return render(request,"profile.html",{"form":form})                 
            
    return render(request,"edit.html",{"form":form})
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error but i solved it by creating my signals example below

then i edited my apps.py as follows:

`from django.apps import AppConfig

class BlogConfig(AppConfig):
default_auto_field = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
name = 'app_name'

```
def ready(self):
    import app_name.signals`
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering your updated question. There is already a save() method in models and it gets called every time you save a model (in your case when you call create_user()). So all you need to do is define a handler function and connect it to the post_save signal.

```
def create_extension(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        # do your thing

models.signals.post_save.connect(create_extension, sender=User, dispatch_uid='create_extension')
```

I usually put the handler functions into a separate file signals.py and add connect() statements at the end of models.py

Answer (score 0):

Just try to create a new user using shell to get access to the admin page then create a profile from admin page for the old user : **python manage.py createsuperuser**

To access to shell, inside your directory project ine terminall type : 
**python manage.py shell**

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit kinda late for this but ill just, share the solution that worked for me on Django 3.0.8...

Error : RelatedObjectDoesNotExist: User has no profile

This the is where my error was directing me to :

```
@login_required
def dashboard(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserEditForm(instance=request.user, data=request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileEditForm(instance=request.user.profile, data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
```

Note: You have to login or your profile to be saved.

Just after creating your account, you should be able to see that you are not logged in and you will have to log in to for your profile be saved and to start working.

Answer (score 0):

Go inside your views, at your create_user function and do these

```
profile = userprofile()
profile.user = user
profile.save()
```

I had similar problems and after 3 days of research, I was able to sort this with just the above 3 lines of codes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your superuser isn't connected to a userprofile.
There are one of the many ways to fix this, one is creating the user from a shell

```
py manage.py shell

> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
> 
> user=User.objects.create_user('UserName', password='AdminPassword')
> user.is_superuser=True   
> user.is_staff=True   
> user.save()
> exit()
```

And another way around being, you can add the following code in the Models.py so that the superuser you create is added to the scope of UserProfile.

```
User.userprofile = property(lambda
u:Userprofile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you created a user prior to setting up authentication on your app, you need to create a new super user on the terminal and then login with that account. I am certain there is no profile created as stated by the error!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30187383)

Answer (score 0):

Had the same error.
Adding the following code in models.py of the apps solved the problem.

```
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if not created:      # if user already exits then ignore
        return
    UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)
post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```